# How to send rows using json_encode method in php?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have number of rows in investment table. I need to retrieve all of them and send them back using `json_encode`.
Here is my code

```
$project_code = $_GET['id'];    
$sql = "select * from investment where project_code = '$project_code'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        while($x1 = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {   $detail = $x1['detail'];
            $sector = $x1['sector'];
        }   
        echo json_encode(array(
            'a' => $detail,
            'b' => $sector
            ));
```

In javascript I wrote following script:

```
$('#myHref').change(function(){
        var value = $('#myHref').val();
        $.get('display_acc.php',{id:value},function(data)
         {
    data = JSON.parse(data); 
     $( '#a' ).html(data.a);
     $( '#b' ).html(data.b);
    });
       });
```

Here my problem is that it returns only data of last rows. I want to receive data of all rows.

I have to display `id a and b` here [image]
I use table to display it.
**Thank in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

--EDIT after OP explanation--

**PHP**

```
$project_code = (int)$_GET['id'];    //better put (int) before to avoid SQL Injection
$sql = "select detail, sector from investment where project_code = '$project_code'"; //better to maintain if you set only the fields you will use
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $return = array('detail'=> array(), 'sector' => array()); //here you can put empty return array or set detail and sector key. Your choice will have impact in your front-end

    $return['my_extra_var' ] = $my_extra_var;
    $i = 0;
    while($x1 = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $return['table'][$i]['detail'] = $x1['detail'];
        $return['table'][$i]['sector'] = $x1['sector'];
        $i++;
    }   
    echo json_encode($return);
```

**Javascript**

```
... your ajax request ...
data = JSON.parse(data);
var tableData = data.table;
$.each(tableData, function(index, value) {
    $('#tableData').append('<tr><td>'+value.detail+'</td><td>'+value.sector+'</td></tr>'); //append row to tbody
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Details</th>
        <th>Sector of Investment</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableData">
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Thnks, one thing I donot mention that I have a extra variable which is not from database table. I mean I need to pass extra one variable which not came from db table so I cnt use it inside while loop. So what should I do.

Comment: Just like `$return['detail'][] = $x1['detail'];` is for array,What should I do to return one more variable.

Comment: You can do `$return['my_extra_variable'] = $my_extra_variable`, outside while loop. Then get in your JS with `data.my_extra_variable`

Comment: ohh, yes It works bt only it repeats the value. But i can't repeat hole row for one array and next row for next array

Comment: will u plz see my image in question.

Comment: Edited. Take a look.

Comment: can't I use `<tr>` and `<td>` ?

Comment: We are using tr/td in this line: `$('#tableData').append('<tr><td>'+value.detail+'</td><td>'+value.sector+'</td></tr>');`. It just a starting point, you can make it better, for sure :)

Comment: it outputs `undefined` and loops many times. I mean I have 3 rows in db table but loops more then 20 times

Comment: Edited. Take a look again ($i part specifically), check your SQL to see if it is correct. Try to do `console.log(data.table)` and check what kind of data you are receiving.

Comment: Gr8, works absolutely.... Plz give me ur email id or any social networking site id like fb or twitter so I can be in touched. N can ask more question if i face in future.

Comment: You're welcome. Just use the chat tool here at stackoverflow (Top left stackexchange -> stackoverflow -> chat), or create a new thread. Your question maybe it's the same of someone else :)

Answer (score 1):

You need  arrays in your loop

```
$project_code = $_GET['id'];    
$sql = "select * from investment where project_code = '$project_code'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $cnt=0;
    while($x1 = mysql_fetch_array($result))

    {   $detail[$cnt] = $x1['detail'];
        $sector[$cnt] = $x1['sector'];
        $cnt++;
    }   
    echo json_encode(array(
        'a' => $detail,
        'b' => $sector
        ));
```

and in javascript loop over the result

Comment: What should i do in javascript code? I mean do i need to add somthng in javascript where i use `data = JSON.parse(data); `

Comment: Yes, in javascript you now obtain an array for a and an array for b then you should loop over the two array for getting the proper value .. Try var_dump( ) the value you echo  so you can understand the json structure you send to client

Comment: how can i use `var_dump( )` in js ?

Comment: How can i display then in `<div id='a'></div>` and `<div id='b'></div>`.

Comment: Not in js ... in php  .. try for debugging  ..but in js you can use an inspector tool like firebugs or  advanced . developer tool like in firefox for developer .. or similar .

Comment: well if you have an array of result you should billd a tabular repoort  with  a dinamic structure   .. using jquery for adding dinamic div eventually for id use a-1, a-2 ....

Comment: WOW !!! I am new to js. I add picture in question, will you plz help me by writing script? It will be really appreciated and other reader also get a big help. plzz

Comment: The manage of a dinamic page i think is a new answer .. i suggets you of post a new question specifically related to this aspect .. in this way  all the community could help you .... try define a proper case ..

Comment: Thnks for ur help. I got array of values of id a and b in js. I saw them console. Nyway thnks again....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not accumulating the two elements.  Try something like this:

```
array_push(your_array_name, $detail, $sector);
```

Then encode your array when all done.

Comment: `your_array_name` means ? what is then name of my array in above code? I mean how to write?